# How can I classify this array of object according to age

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hello i have this aray of objects

```js
[{
        name: "person1",
        age: 23,
    },
    {
        name: "person2",
        age: 23,
    },
    {
        name: "person3",
        age: 24,
    },
    {
        name: "person4",
        age: 24,
    },
    {
        name: "person5",
        age: 25,
    }
]
```

so what i want is to classify this array according to age to get

```js
[
    [{
            name: "person1",
            age: 23,
        },
        {
            name: "person2",
            age: 23,
        }
    ],
    [{
            name: "person3",
            age: 24,
        },
        {
            name: "person4",
            age: 24,
        }
    ],
    [{
        name: "person5",
        age: 25,
    }]
]
```

I can do it the old fashioned way, but what I want with less code, it's  okey to use lodash to get the desired result .

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: So you want to *group* by age.

Comment: problem solved using lodash 
_.groupBy( [
  {
    name: "person1",
    age: 23,
  },
  {
    name: "person2",
    age: 23,
  },
  {
    name: "person3",
    age: 24,
  },
    {
    name: "person4",
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    name: "person5",
    age: 25,
  }
], 'age');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object where the items are grouped by age stored as a property, then call [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) on the result:

```js
const arr=[{name:"person1",age:23},{name:"person2",age:23},{name:"person3",age:24},{name:"person4",age:24},{name:"person5",age:25}];

const byAge = arr.reduce((a,b) => (a[b.age] ? a[b.age].push(b) : a[b.age] = [b], a), {})
const result = Object.values(byAge)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by using lodash

```
const MockData = [ 
 { name: "person1", age: 23, },
 { name: "person2", age: 23, },
 { name: "person3", age: 24, },
 { name: "person4", age: 24, },
 { name: "person5", age: 25, } ];


 _.groupBy(MockData, 'age'); // we get the desired result !
```